# How to hide directories on linux ssh server

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, ssh

I run ssh server on Ubuntu, it's a local server just for my family. I've managed to hide some directories using `sudo chmod 770 .directory/`. All those directories are already hidden with dot (.). When I connect to my server from Windows 10 using network disk mapping, I can still see those directories in the file explorer, they are still listed.

I want to hide some directories from client PCs, especialy Windows 10 clients.

Comment: What software are you using to map network disks via SSH? Regular Windows does only SMB and WebDAV...

Comment: I installed WinFsp and SSHFS-Win on the Windows 10. I use network disk mapping in File Explorer